# How to vertically center-align an inline tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I have a macro that creates a `tikzpicture` with an unknown height.  I want to use it inline in equations, and I want it to to vertically line up with `=` and other operators.  The code I have so far will draw a permutation and then draw a box around it.  The first macro has a known height, so I can set the `baseline` of the `tikzpicture` and align it as I want.  The second one does not have a known height, and here I've set the `baseline` to work for the most common usage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% This works for fixed-height pictures.
\newcommand{\permute}[1]
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2ex,y=-2ex, baseline=-3.5ex]
    \foreach \from [count=\to] in {#1}{
      \draw (\from,1) -- (\to,2);
    }
    \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,2.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

% This no longer works because the height isn't known in advance.
\newcommand{\compoundPermutation}[1]
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2ex,y=-2ex, baseline=-4.5ex]
    \foreach \list [count=\row] in {#1} {
      \foreach \from [count=\to] in \list {
        \draw (\from,\row) -- (\to,\row+1);
      }
    }
    \foreach \list [count=\count] in {#1} {
      \ifx \count \row
        \foreach \from [count=\to] in \list {
        }
        \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,\row+1.5);
      \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item The group operation, $\oplus$, can be thought of as stacking: \\
        \permute{2,3,1}$\oplus$\permute{1,3,2}=\compoundPermutation{{2,3,1},{1,3,2}}=\permute{2,1,3}
  \item Sometimes, for brevity, we omit the operator's symbol: \\
        \permute{2,3,1}\permute{1,3,2}=\permute{2,1,3}
  \item If we look at it this way, it's clear that we satisfy associativity: \\
        \permute{2,3,1}\permute{1,3,2}\permute{3,1,2}=\compoundPermutation{{2,3,1},{1,3,2}}\permute{3,1,2}=\permute{2,3,1}\compoundPermutation{{1,3,2},{3,1,2}}=\compoundPermutation{{2,3,1},{1,3,2},{3,1,2}}=\permute{3,2,1}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This code produces a picture like this:

[image: Result so far]

What can I change so that the vertical center of the `tikzpicture` always lines up with the vertical center of the text?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I should've been clearer initially.  I've added the question to the end of the post.  Originally, I was trying to get that across with "I want to use it inline in equations, and I want it to to vertically line up with `=` and other operators."

Comment: `baseline=(current bounding box.center)`?

Comment: That's close to what I want...a screenshot is [here](http://imgur.com/a/btsjB).  That aligns the center of the picture with the baseline of the text, but I want the center at the same height as an `=`.  That's about `1ex` higher, and I couldn't figure out a way to do simple arithmetic like `baseline=1ex+(current bounding box.center)` or `baseline=(1ex+current bounding box.center)`.

Comment: At the end of the picture `\coordinate (p) at ([yshift=1ex]current bounding box.center);` and then use `baseline=(p)`. Probably there is a more elegant way. `(p)` need not be defined when you write `baseline=(p)` so long as it is defined somewhere in the picture ....

Comment: Perfect!  I changed it to `[yshift=-0.5ex]`, since that looked better than `-1` (and I think the negative is because my positive `y` points down).  If you write this up as an answer, I'll accept it so others can see more easily.

Comment: @cfr Maybe `baseline=([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box)`.

Comment: @Symbol1 I couldn't get that to work. (That's what I tried first.)

Comment: @cfr Interesting... Since `baseline` involves `\tikz@scan@one@point`, there should be no problem...

Comment: Unrelated: you want to have the whole equation in math mode to get proper spacing, not just `\oplus`. I.e. `$\permute{2,3,1}\oplus\permute{1,3,2}=\compoundPermutation{{2,3,1},{1,3,2}}=\permute{2,1,3}$`.

Comment: @Symbol1 I think it just needs `{}`, actually. Then it works fine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. And to get rid of the `\\ ` for line breaks.

Comment: @Symbol1 I incorporated your suggestion (with added brackets) into my answer. Let me know if you object, please!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I also used your comment in answering so, again, let me know if you object, please.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., yes, that makes the horizontal spacing around `\oplus` look much better as well.  I was just nervous about putting a picture inside a maths environment, which I suppose I shouldn't be.

Comment: @cfr no object. I am happy to see someone do the dirty job (writing an answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get things centered about the math axis, I added a `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` to wrap around your prior macro definitions.  I also expressed the complete relations in math mode, to get proper spacing around the operators.  Per cfr's comment, I removed the `baseline` specification from the two macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% This works for fixed-height pictures.
\newcommand{\permute}[1]
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2ex,y=-2ex]
    \foreach \from [count=\to] in {#1}{
      \draw (\from,1) -- (\to,2);
    }
    \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,2.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}}}}

% This no longer works because the height isn't known in advance.
\newcommand{\compoundPermutation}[1]
  {\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2ex,y=-2ex]
    \foreach \list [count=\row] in {#1} {
      \foreach \from [count=\to] in \list {
        \draw (\from,\row) -- (\to,\row+1);
      }
    }
    \foreach \list [count=\count] in {#1} {
      \ifx \count \row
        \foreach \from [count=\to] in \list {
        }
        \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,\row+1.5);
      \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item The group operation, $\oplus$, can be thought of as stacking: \\
        $\permute{2,3,1}\oplus\permute{1,3,2}=\compoundPermutation{{2,3,1},{1,3,2}}=\permute{2,1,3}$
  \item Sometimes, for brevity, we omit the operator's symbol: \\
        $\permute{2,3,1}\permute{1,3,2}=\permute{2,1,3}$
  \item If we look at it this way, it's clear that we satisfy associativity: \\
        $\permute{2,3,1}\permute{1,3,2}\permute{3,1,2}=\compoundPermutation{{2,3,1},{1,3,2}}\permute{3,1,2}=\permute{2,3,1}\compoundPermutation{{1,3,2},{3,1,2}}=\compoundPermutation{{2,3,1},{1,3,2},{3,1,2}}=\permute{3,2,1}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cfr Thanks.  I removed the baseline specifications on the two macros.

Comment: Good. (+1) I think this is a better solution than mine. I'd never heard of `\vcenter` before.

Comment: @cfr Yes, it alleviates the need to guess where the math-centered axis is.  Incidentally, I believe that `\vcenter{\hbox{$.$}}` is equivalent to `\setbox0=\hbox{$.$}\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox-.5\ht0+.5\dp0\relax}{\copy0}`

Comment: That being so, I can't imagine why anybody would have introduced a wrapper for it.

Comment: @cfr When I say "equivalent", I mean "functionally equivalent".  For example, `\vcenter` works only in math mode.  I don't know the actual code for `\vcenter`and if it performs additional tests, but it is a TeX primitive.

Answer (score 11):

You can use any coordinate for `baseline`, so long as it is defined somewhere in the picture. So

```
\coordinate (p) at ([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center);
```

with

```
baseline=(p)
```

will work. Or, if you surround it by curly brackets, you can add the shift into the argument to `baseline`, [as Symbol1 suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381008/how-to-vertically-center-align-an-inline-tikzpicture?noredirect=1#comment943967_381008).

```
baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)}
```

You should not use `\\` to break lines outside special environments, such as `tabular` and `array`. Leave a blank line or use `\par` instead.

Moreover, the entire equations should be in maths mode to ensure proper spacing, [as Torbjørn T. noted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381008/how-to-vertically-center-align-an-inline-tikzpicture?noredirect=1#comment944090_381008). For example,

```
$\permute{2,3,1}\permute{1,3,2}=\permute{2,1,3}$
```

[image: adjusted equations]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% This works for fixed-height pictures.
\newcommand{\permute}[1]
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2ex,y=-2ex, baseline=-3.5ex]
    \foreach \from [count=\to] in {#1}{
      \draw (\from,1) -- (\to,2);
    }
    \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,2.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

% This no longer works because the height isn't known in advance.
\newcommand{\compoundPermutation}[1]
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2ex,y=-2ex, baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)}]
    \foreach \list [count=\row] in {#1} {
      \foreach \from [count=\to] in \list {
        \draw (\from,\row) -- (\to,\row+1);
      }
    }
    \foreach \list [count=\count] in {#1} {
      \ifx \count \row
        \foreach \from [count=\to] in \list {
        }
        \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,\row+1.5);
      \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item The group operation, $\oplus$, can be thought of as stacking: \par
        $\permute{2,3,1}\oplus\permute{1,3,2}=\compoundPermutation{{2,3,1},{1,3,2}}=\permute{2,1,3}$
  \item Sometimes, for brevity, we omit the operator's symbol: \par
        $\permute{2,3,1}\permute{1,3,2}=\permute{2,1,3}$
  \item If we look at it this way, it's clear that we satisfy associativity: \par
        $\permute{2,3,1}\permute{1,3,2}\permute{3,1,2}=\compoundPermutation{{2,3,1},{1,3,2}}\permute{3,1,2}=\permute{2,3,1}\compoundPermutation{{1,3,2},{3,1,2}}=\compoundPermutation{{2,3,1},{1,3,2},{3,1,2}}=\permute{3,2,1}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```