# How to equate a text on left hand side to an inserted image on right hand side horizontally?

Tags: spacing, graphics, equations, formatting

I want the text in left hand side to be equated to an inserted image on right hand side as shown below:[image]

Here, i wish the text in left hand side to be written in latex and equate it horizontally to an inserted image on right hand side. Also, how to insert text between images horizontally?

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming by your use of the term "inserted image," that you have an external graphic.  You can use `\includegraphics` (also)  in math mode to insert images.  To get them vertically aligned with the math axis, the easiest way is to apply `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` to the graphic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
G\oplus H &= \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=3em]{example-image-a}}}
\oplus \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=3em]{example-image-b}}}\\
&= \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=3em]{example-image-c}}}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

egreg suggests the even simpler construction, using the `valign` key of `\includegraphics` (`adjustbox` package required):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
G\oplus H &= \includegraphics[height=3em,valign=c]{example-image-a}
\oplus \includegraphics[height=3em,valign=c]{example-image-b}\\
&= \includegraphics[height=3em,valign=c]{example-image-c}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{gathered}\includegraphics[...]{...}\end{gathered}` is simpler, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg I note the vertical alignment, with your suggested change, is slightly different (i.e., uncentered).

Comment: Indeed! There is a strut added, which raises the whole thing.

Comment: @egreg Hmm.  One of the few times that adding a `\strut` isn't helpful or at least innocuous.

Comment: Here's a simpler construction then: `\includegraphics[height=3em,valign=c]{example-image-b}` (requires `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`). By the way, the example images have lowercase names; on some operating systems this may not make a difference, on others it could.

Comment: @egreg Thank you.  I should remember about the lowercase filename, but since it doesn't bite me on my system, I can forget with impunity.

Comment: @steven B. Thanks a lot. Instead of using external image if i wish to draw the same graphs in latex how would i do it?

Comment: @gete There is the `tikz` package for drawing your own graphics.  See my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381008/how-to-vertically-center-align-an-inline-tikzpicture/381175#381175 for something very much like you are asking here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  vcenter/.style={
    baseline={([yshift=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]
                    current bounding box.center)},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
G\oplus H &=
\begin{tikzpicture}[vcenter]
\coordinate (1) at (0,1);
\coordinate (2) at (0.866,0.5);
\coordinate (3) at (0,0);
\coordinate (c) at (1.732,0.5);
\fill (1) circle (1pt) node[above] {\tiny 1};
\fill (2) circle (1pt) node[left] {\tiny 2};
\fill (3) circle (1pt) node[below] {\tiny 3};
\fill (c) circle (1pt) node[right] {\tiny c};
\draw (1)--(2)--(3)--cycle;
\draw [red] (1)--(c);
\draw [red] (2)--(c);
\draw [red] (3)--(c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\oplus
\begin{tikzpicture}[vcenter]
\coordinate (a) at (0,1);
\coordinate (b) at (0,0);
\coordinate (c) at (0.866,0.5);
\fill (a) circle (1pt) node[above] {\tiny a};
\fill (b) circle (1pt) node[below] {\tiny b};
\fill (c) circle (1pt) node[right] {\tiny c};
\draw (a)--(b);
\draw [red] (a)--(c);
\draw [red] (b)--(c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
&=
\begin{tikzpicture}[vcenter]
\coordinate (1) at (0,1);
\coordinate (2) at (0.866,0.5);
\coordinate (3) at (0,0);
\coordinate (a) at (1.732,1);
\coordinate (b) at (1.732,0);
\coordinate (c) at (2.598,0.5);
\fill (1) circle (1pt) node[above] {\tiny 1};
\fill (2) circle (1pt) node[left] {\tiny 2};
\fill (3) circle (1pt) node[below] {\tiny 3};
\fill (a) circle (1pt) node[above] {\tiny a};
\fill (b) circle (1pt) node[below] {\tiny b};
\fill (c) circle (1pt) node[right] {\tiny c};
\draw (1)--(2)--(3)--cycle;
\draw (a)--(b);
\draw [red] (1)--(c);
\draw [red] (2)--(c);
\draw [red] (3)--(c);
\draw [red] (a)--(c);
\draw [red] (b)--(c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

These are very simple diagrams and the code should be almost self-explaining. The style defined in the preamble is found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302507/4427 and it copes with the alignment of the picture similar to the one suggested by Steven in his answer.

The idea is to define some coordinates and then use them for drawing circles and segments. Labels are placed as nodes next to the circles.